# test class for attachments for events in salesforce

Tags: apex, code-coverage, test-setup

Hi can anyone please help me with a test class for below two methods

```java
global static void insertAttachment(string eventid, Map<String, Object> json_body) {
        
        try {
            Map<String, Object> attachment = (Map<String, Object>) json_body.get('Attachment');
            
            if ( attachment == null ) {
                return;    
            }
            
            Event e = [ SELECT ID FROM Event WHERE ID = : eventid ][0];
            
            string base64str = (string) json_body.get('Body');
            
            Attachment at = new Attachment();
            at.Name = (string) json_body.get('FileName'); 
            at.ParentID = e.ID;
            at.contentType = (string) json_body.get('ContentType'); 
            at.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64str);
            
            insert at;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        } 
    }
global static void insertAttendees(Map<String, Object> json_body, ID new_event_id) {
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> attendees = (List<Map<String, Object>>) json_body.get('Attendees');
            
            if ( attendees == null )
                attendees = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
            
            // new_event.IsGroupEvent = true;

            for ( Map<String, Object> o : attendees ) {
                string email = (string) o.get('Email');
                
                List<Contact> conts = [ SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE Email = : email ];
                Contact cont = conts[0];
                
                ID relation_id = null;

                if ( cont == null ) {
                    List<User> users = [ SELECT ID FROM User WHERE Email = : email ];
                    User usr = users[0];
                    
                    if ( usr == null ) {
                        List<Lead> leads = [ SELECT ID FROM Lead WHERE Email = : email ];
                        Lead ld = leads[0];
                        
                        relation_id = ld.ID;
                    }
                    
                    relation_id = usr.ID;
                } else {
                    relation_id = cont.ID;
                }

                if ( relation_id != null ) {  
                    EventRelation er = new EventRelation();
                    er.EventId = new_event_id;
                    er.RelationId = relation_id;
                    
                    insert er;
                }
            }   
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One of the keys to a successful question here is to show us what you've tried so far, and pointing to a narrow and specific thing that you're stuck on. Otherwise, it's a "do my work for me" request instead of a "help me learn how to overome this issue" request.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of our standard "How to write tests" question because the answer to "How do I test thing X?" is usually "there's nothing special about thing X, you test it the same as you would with any other code". It contains some good advice and resources for learning how to write tests. If you go through all of that and still need help with your tests, then you should [edit] your question to show us your attempt and point out what, specifically, you're having trouble with.